# Patch Request only with Wi-fi

Tags: react-native

I'm doing a Mobile App with React Native that needs to send a Photo to a server by a Patch Request, but only when the phone is in a Wi-fi Network. When it's using a mobile network, the App should store the photo and send the request when connects to Wi-Fi.

There is any way of doing that?

I already send the photo, but no matter if is 4G or Wi-Fi.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `componentWillMount()` you can use [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo) to check if it is `wifi` or not.

If it's `wifi` then post it otherwise store that in somewhere (for example [`AsyncStorage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) and then send it later.